# Looping through Azure DevOps Work List Result values with Powershell prints nothing to console

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Using the following docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/Work%2520Items/List?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=vsts-rest-5.0, I have an api call that gets a list of workitems.

I convert that to Json in my devops build yml via a powershell script but looping through the "value" array doesn't seem to print anything to my devops console. Any help on syntax?

```
$jsonResp = $($workItemResponse | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)
Write-Host "json formatted response"
Write-Host $jsonResp.value

foreach($item in $($jsonResp.value))
{
        $releaseNotesHtml += "<div>" + $item.fields.System.Id + "</div>"
        Write-Host $item.fields.System.Id
        Write-Host $item.fields.System.Title
        Write-Host $item.fields.System.State
        Write-Host $item.fields.System.Description
}
```

I've also tried this, with no success.

```
foreach($item in $jsonResp.value)
{
            $releaseNotesHtml += "<div>" + $item.fields.System.Id + "</div>"
            Write-Host $item.fields.System.Id
            Write-Host $item.fields.System.Title
            Write-Host $item.fields.System.State
            Write-Host $item.fields.System.Description
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following format:

```
$token = "<pat>"

$orgurl = "https://dev.azure.com/<org_name>/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=200,250,300&api-version=5.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$wiResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $orgurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

foreach($item in $wiResponse.value)
{
        $releaseNotesHtml += "<div>" + $item.id + "</div>"
        Write-Host $item.id
        Write-Host $item.fields.'System.Title'
        Write-Host $item.fields.'System.State'
        Write-Host $item.fields.'System.Description'
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: doing Write-Host $jsonResp.value also prints nothing...but doing Write-Host $jsonResp displays exactly like the Microsoft docs show.

Comment: @J.G.Sable what do you have in the `$jsonResp.count` ?

Comment: $jsonResp.count returns 1, yet the "count" if I do $jsonResp says 3

Comment: @J.G.Sable I do not think that you need to use `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100`. you can use `$workItemResponse.value`

Comment: If I don't do that, it's just System.Object[]

Comment: @J.G.Sable check my updated answer, it works on my org

Comment: Got it, thanks. I think it's because I had application/json in quotes and therefore it wasn't recognizing it as a keyword.